# Unable to find "Create New Message" option in Marketing Cloud MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, appcenter

I would like to set up an SMS message like the examples on [this page](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/mobileconnect-api/using-the-mobileconnect-api.html), but I am unable to find the "Create New Message" option in the App Center. I have created an API Integration app but I do not know where I can create sms messages like those listed on the page I linked above.

I have also looked for this option in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Hub and still cannot find it.

I'd be happy to follow the demos on [the page](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/mobileconnect-api/using-the-mobileconnect-api.html). Can someone please point me to the "Create a New Message" option?

Thank you very much and let me know if you need anything from me.

EDIT: After looking at the second image on [this page](http://www.exacttarget.com/products/mobile-marketing/engage-via-mobile-messages), I think I need the MobileConnect page to create a new message. Sorry if this is a basic question but how can I access mobile connect? I cannot find it anywhere in the Marketing Cloud Hub or in the App Center.

Answer (score 3):

When you log into your account you should see it in the drop down menu.

Once you click MobileConnect you will see "Create Message" on the right-hand side. [image: Salesforce Marketing Cloud MobileConnect]

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. When I hover over mobile I do not see MobileConnect or MobilePush. I assume this means I do not have this service with the account I purchased?